# Function to display image

Tags: php, image, function

I have a Php function and I want it to display a photo...

```
<?php
function getImg ($src)
{
    switch ($src)
    {
        case "Sunny":
            echo "<img src='fakepath/sunny.png'>";
            break;
        case "Sad":
            echo "<img src='fakepath/sad.png'>";
            break;
        case "Smile":
            echo "<img src='fakepath/smile.png'>";
            break;
default: echo "nothing"; break;
    }
}

$style = "Sad";
getImg($style);
```

After `getImg($style)`, it does not echo anything.

What's wrong?

Comment: Maybe the image does not exists. The code works fine , Press Ctrl+U to view the source.

Comment: Is the function is called correctly? try echo out something in the function.

Comment: function and code seems okay, can you check the image src path and is image exists?

Comment: code works fine, image is missing, check your image exist on this path? fakepath/sad.png according to the above function.

Comment: add a `default:` case to your switch that outputs something that you can see

Comment: Replace `'fakepath/sunny.png'` with `'www.domain.com/fakepath/sunny.png'` do the same to all image paths.

Comment: @Zeeshan i tried to echo "Hi" but it doesn't display anything as well.

Comment: @AndyJones code ran in my default's echo. :/

Comment: @Sarah http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/eyc-n75

Comment: I can't get over how people are downvoting my "working" answer. @Sarah Pfft.. no biggie, as long as you're happy :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're answer *works* because it is no different from the working code above.

Comment: Well, I for one would sure like to know why Sarah accepted it in the first place. Why don't you ask her yourself? @Phil

Comment: there will be path error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$src` when calling the function, and not `$style`

```
<?php
function getImg ($src)
{
    switch ($src)
    {
        case "Sunny":
            echo "<img src='fakepath/sunny.png'>";
            break;
        case "Sad":
            echo "<img src='fakepath/sad.png'>";
            break;
        case "Smile":
            echo "<img src='fakepath/smile.png'>";
            break;
    }
}

$src = "Sad";
getImg($src);
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, doesn't know how functions and variables work.

Comment: Because, the function's variables don't match when "calling" the function and its parameter. @user1844933

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$style` is set in the global scope where it is passed into `getImg()`. Within the function, the argument is referred to as `$src`. There is nothing wrong with the original code. Outside the function scope, you can name the variable anything you want

Comment: And have you tried it yourself @Phil Use the OP's code as it is. Get 3 different images like I did, and then use `$style = "Sad";` then `$style = "Sunny";` then `$style = "Smile";` and you/they will see that they will all echo the SAME image. I tested the OP's code before, and mine after. It....... works.

Comment: No, the OP's code does not work as it is. Did you even bother testing it yourself? @user1844933 Like I did? yeah, I didn't think so.

Comment: Yes, I tested... again I can say it is working code... no doubt

Comment: Hey, if it will make you all happy, I'll just delete the answer and you can go nitpick another one after that, ok? Now you go and ask the OP why she posted the question, then accepted my answer. Phoque if I know.

Comment: On second thought, I'll leave it here. The question is closed. It works without the "default" case.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's illogical and said how correct/accepted and good answer's can be down voted! The only think i/we can do is to make the world a little bit fairer ;)

Comment: @Rizier123 We can't win them all, but we can all be fair ;)

Answer (score 0):

Working fine after adding a default clause

```
function getImg ($src)
{
    switch ($src)
    {
        case "Sunny":
            echo "<img src='fakepath/sunny.png'>";
            break;
        case "Sad":
            echo "<img src='fakepath/sad.png'>";
            break;
        case "Smile":
            echo "<img src='fakepath/smile.png'>";
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }
}

$style = "Sad";
getImg($style);
```